# How to know whether it is inside or outside building using IndoorAtlas

Tags: android

I'm using IndoorAtlas SDK. I already succed to show my current location inside building.

The problem is when i'm going outside building, it still show my location inside building.

Is there any ideas ?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419995/determine-if-current-location-is-inside-or-outside-building-with-indooratlas/30497476#30497476

Comment: Jukka.. can u see this thread ? i really need your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723347/countdowntimer-didnt-work-in-indooratlas

Comment: That's a generic Java/Android issue for which I'm sure you can find solution or get more help. During day time, I can try to answer questions related to IndoorAtlas SDK only.